# Java Thread join() with sleep interval causing problem

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was doing tutorial on concurrent programming and saw .join() method is used to make sure the thread will run until finish before continue the rest of code.

However, when i trying use 2 thread to increment and decrements a variable like 100 times (initiate value: 2000), the end result suppose to show 2000, but it show either more than 2000 or less than 2000.
It only works fine and consistently show 2000 when i uncomment the `Thread.sleep` in **main** method

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SharedObj sharedObj = new SharedObj();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadMinus(sharedObj));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadPlus(sharedObj));
        thread1.start();
//        try {
//            Thread.sleep(100);
//        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
        thread2.start();

        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("number is: " + sharedObj.num);
        System.out.println("increment count: " + sharedObj.countPos);
        System.out.println("decrement count: " + sharedObj.countNeg);

    }
}

class SharedObj {
    public int num;
    public int countPos = 0;
    public int countNeg = 0;

    public SharedObj() {
        num = 2000;
    }

    public void change(int x) {
        num += x;
        if (x < 0) {
            countNeg++;
        } else {
            countPos++;
        }
        System.out.println("number is: " + num + " with operation: " + x);
    }
}

class ThreadMinus implements Runnable {
    SharedObj sharedObj;

    public ThreadMinus(SharedObj sharedObj) {
        this.sharedObj = sharedObj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            sharedObj.change(-1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class ThreadPlus implements Runnable {
    SharedObj sharedObj;

    public ThreadPlus(SharedObj sharedObj) {
        this.sharedObj = sharedObj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            sharedObj.change(+1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the sleep/join causing problems. It's the race condition that you're incrementing the same variable without securing it. Add `synchronized` to SharedObj#change and you should be fine:

```
public synchronized void change(int x) { //...
```

Comment: so even though I put .join, but those thread are still compete each other to access that variable? and the reason why put sleep between .start() can seems like it fix the issue is because both thread has different run interval (got some delay) so causing the variable can incre/decre properly?

Comment: @oks1998 Yes, the `join()` is merely there for waiting for the threads to finish - they still run concurrently and can mess up their data. It's hard to say why a `sleep` changes the behavior, and I wouldn't put too much thought into it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you see is a classic case of a Race Condition. 
Consider `num += x;` It looks like one operation to you, but in reality it's multiple operations in the CPU.

In simple terms it's 
 1. temp1 = num;
 2. temp2 = x;
 3. temp3 = temp1 + temp2
 4. num = temp3

It's actually happening in the registers in the CPU, so you don't obviously see it when you write Java.

When you have multiple threads running concurrently and are executing those instructions, you may end up with an unexpected result.

For example lets start with x = 1 and num = 2.

Thread A is executing :

```
 1. temp1a = num; 
 2. temp2a = x; 
 3. temp3a = temp1a + temp2a; 
 4. num = temp3a;
```

And Thread B is executing

```
 1. temp1b = num;
 2. temp2b = x;
 3. temp3b = temp1b + temp2b;
 4. num = temp3b;
```

Now if they are executing those operations concurrently you may end up with this order:

```
 1. temp1a = num; //2
 2. temp2a = x; //1
 3. temp3a = temp1a + temp2a; //3

 4. temp1b = num; //2
 5. temp2b = x; //1
 6. temp3b = temp1b + temp2b; //3
 7. num = temp3b; //3

 8. num = temp3a; //3
```

So although you incremented `num` twice, you got the result 3, instead of 4. 
That is a race condition. There are many ways to avoid it, and synchronization is one of them, but there are other techniques.

If you'd like to understand it better, I really recommend this online course.
https://www.udemy.com/java-multithreading-concurrency-performance-optimization/?couponCode=CONCURRENCY

It's like really cheap, and you can finish it in a few hours, but it explains it really well with examples, absolutely from scratch, and it goes into very advanced topics in concurrency. It's a good time investment.

In your case just adding synchronized like this:

```
public synchronized void change(int x) {
    num += x;
    if (x < 0) {
        countNeg++;
    } else {
        countPos++;
    }
    System.out.println("number is: " + num + " with operation: " + x);
}
```

will solve the problem, but it's not a magic bullet. You should take the time to understand why it's solving the problem in this case, and may not solve it in another.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are trying update the value of the same variable concurrently. By observing the output you can find that at some point the program fails to update the value because of this concurrency. You can solve this issue either by making the method 'change' as 'synchronized' or by increasing the sleep time for each thread keeping the sleep in the Main method.

Answer (score 0):

join() is in the wrong position.

```
 public class ThreadJoinTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SharedObj sharedObj = new SharedObj();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadMinus(sharedObj));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadPlus(sharedObj));
        thread1.start();
        thread1.join();
//        try {
//            Thread.sleep(100);
//        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
        thread2.start();
        thread2.join();
//        try {
//            thread1.join();
//            thread2.join();
//        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
        System.out.println("number is: " + sharedObj.num);
        System.out.println("increment count: " + sharedObj.countPos);
        System.out.println("decrement count: " + sharedObj.countNeg);

    }
}

class SharedObj {
    public int num;
    public int countPos = 0;
    public int countNeg = 0;

    public SharedObj() {
        num = 2000;
    }

    public void change(int x) {
        num += x;
        if (x < 0) {
            countNeg++;
        } else {
            countPos++;
        }
        System.out.println("number is: " + num + " with operation: " + x);
    }
}

class ThreadMinus implements Runnable {
    SharedObj sharedObj;

    public ThreadMinus(SharedObj sharedObj) {
        this.sharedObj = sharedObj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            sharedObj.change(-1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class ThreadPlus implements Runnable {
    SharedObj sharedObj;

    public ThreadPlus(SharedObj sharedObj) {
        this.sharedObj = sharedObj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            sharedObj.change(+1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);`enter code here`
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would simply make the Threads execute one after another, which kind of defeats the purpose (concurrency).

Comment: ya, it will run in sequence, not concurrently anymore